# How do I go back to a variable in python?

Tags: python, variables

i've been working on this script in Python for a while. However, i've come across a problem:
In my code, the user types in a command and some text appears (sort of like MS-DOS.), but i don't know how to get it back to the question. (at the moment the program just ends.)

Here is a sample of my script:

```
command=raw_input("j;/")

command1="help"

command2="jver"


if command==command1:

   print "List of commands"

   print""

   print""

   print"help = shows all commands"

   print ""

   print "jver = Version of MS-Josh"

   #Code here so that it goes back to the j;/ raw_input question.

elif command==command2:

     print "MS-Josh version 3.12."

     print ""

     print "memory used: 7,117 bytes"

     print "memory on computer: 1,434,078 bytes"

     print "memory free: 1,426,961"

      #Code here so that it goes back to the j;/ raw_input question.

else:
   print "incorrect command"
```

Comment: can you post an example? user inputs --> what do you expect?

Comment: You're looking for loops and functions - these should be covered in any programming introduction or tutorial for beginners, so I'd suggest you go read one. StackOverflow is not a site intended to teach you the absolute programming basics; please read [all of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and don't ask questions which are off-topic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
while True:
    ...
```

This will put you back at the top if you place the statement at the top of your script.

Like this:

```
while True:
   command=raw_input("j;/")
   command1="help"
   command2="jver"


   if command==command1:
      print "List of commands"
      print""
      print""
      print"help = shows all commands"
      print ""
      print "jver = Version of MS-Josh"
   elif command==command2:
        print "MS-Josh version 3.12."
        print ""
        print "memory used: 7,117 bytes"
        print "memory on computer: 1,434,078 bytes"
        print "memory free: 1,426,961"
   else:
      print "incorrect command"
```

Answer (score 0):

use iteration to loop your commands and GIVE  USER WAY TO EXIT

```
while True:
   command=raw_input("j;/")
   command1="help"
   command2="jver"
   command3='end'

   if command == command3:
      return
   elif command==command1:
      ...... your code
```